# Infinite vector problem related to the continuum hypothesis

Tags: vector-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

I developed an algorithm that might map the countable ordinal numbers (ones with just a countable number of predecessors) into a subset of the reals without using the axiom of choice. It leads to the following question: Consider infinite dimensional vectors with only Natural numbers as entries. Comparison with continued fractions maps these vectors into the irrational numbers greater than 1. The cardinality of such vectors is the same as the cardinality of the real numbers. Consider any subset $V$ of those vectors and the set $W(V)$ which consists of all the finite sets that can be written as $\{(v_a,n_a)|v_a\in V, n_a \text{is a natural number, no repeats among the }v_a\}$. For any $w \in W(V)$ we define $sum(w) = \sum v_a n_a$. We wish to consider only $V$ such that $sum(w_\alpha) = sum(w_\beta)$ implies that $w_\alpha = w_\beta$. Essentially, $V$ is a basis for $\{sum(w)|w \in W(V)\}$. Is there an uncountable set $V$ with those properties? If not the output of the algorithm is only a countable set. If so the algorithm probably defines an uncountable subset of the real numbers that is well ordered. I would prefer a proof that such a $V$ exists without using the axiom of choice. Off hand if it wasn't for the restriction that the sums are all finite, the answer would clearly be no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such uncountable set.

Note that if we can find an uncountable family $X$ of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ s.t. intersection of any two sets from the family is finite, we can build necessary $V$ from it: for each $\alpha \in X$ add $v_\alpha$ to $V$ - vector that has $1$ on coordinates with numbers in $\alpha$, and $0$ on others.

Assume that we have $\sum_\limits{\alpha \in Y} n_\alpha v_\alpha = 0$ for some finite $Y \subset X$ and non-zero integers $n_\alpha$. Fix some $\alpha_0 \in Y$. By property of $X$, $\alpha_0 \cap \left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in Y, \alpha \neq \alpha_0} \alpha\right)$ is finite, and thus $\alpha_0 \setminus \left(\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in Y, \alpha \neq \alpha_0} \alpha\right)$ is non-empty. Choose some $i$ from it - then $i$-th coordinate of our sum is equal to $n_{\alpha_0}$, and, as the sum is $0$, $n_{\alpha_0} = 0$.

To construct such $X$, see, for example, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/89308/11507) answer.

However, it's not clear, how you are going to construct uncountable well-ordered subset of $\mathbb R$ using such $V$. You definitely can't build an uncountable well-ordered subset of $\mathbb R$ in ZF, because axiom of determinacy is consistent with ZF, and from it you have that 1) any uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ has cardinality of continuum; 2) continuum can't be well-ordered.

Comment: Agreed that to any countable V, one can find another vector to add to it. However to say that one can then add an uncountable number of vectors and keep the same properties seems to be a hand waving argument I am trying to avoid. If you replace V with L the set of countable limit ordinals plus the first limit ordinal, the the set {sum(w)} becomes the set of countable ordinal numbers. This gives a nice correspondence. My algorithm (not using the axiom of choice) builds a V from L / {sum(w)} but runs into that hand waving argument. A close examination of my assumptions is the L is a set.

Comment: In my example, it's not handwaving, it's essentially axiom of replacement: for every subset of $\mathbb N$ there exists one corresponding vector, so for family of subsets $V$ there exist a set of vectors containing exactly vectors corresponding to some sets from $V$.

Comment: Sorry, what is "first limit ordinal" here? And I don't understand your construction with ordinals at all (it probably deserves it's own question if necessary). Anyway, the answer to your original question is "ZF proves that such $V$ exists, but ZF doesn't prove that there exists well-orderable uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$".

Comment: Sorry, did not mead "first limit ordinal", I meant the first ordinal, 1. Any ordinal number can be written as a finite combination of 1 and the limit ordinals. Any finite combination of the vectors in V is by definition unique (ignoring the order they are combined. V mirrors the ordinal numbers. My algorithm constructs such a V provided it can go from the countable to the uncountable. There is a minor question is the 'set' of countable ordinals really a set or alternatively are all sets that can be well ordered countable?

Comment: The first ordinal is $0$, but it doesn't matter. I don't understand how do you link $V$ to ordinals. ZF proves that there is no largest ordinal - in particular, there is no set of all ordinals, and there are uncountable ordinals. However, that doesn't imply there are uncountable well orderable subsets of $\mathbb R$, because without choice, two sets can have incomporable cardinalities.

Comment: My algorithm uses a diagonal argument to find the next vector to associate with the next next limit ordinal (as long as only a countable number of them have been found so far). It does not use the axiom of choice anywhere; it dictates everything. Assuming this in the limit it does this an uncountable number of times, the association is complete. The question is how justified is that assumption.

Comment: I think this should be a separate question rather than discussion in comments.

Comment: It is really what I meant in the original question "If so the algorithm probably defines an uncountable subset of the real numbers that is well ordered. " What is really needed is someone to look over the algorithm and see what they think. it is a 3 page document,

Comment: Well, you can try to split it to several parts and ask separate questions. But as I said, you can be sure that it's impossible to prove in ZF existence of uncountable well-orderable subset of $\mathbb R$.